# adobe flash cs5: actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, camera

When I preview this the video quality is really bad, and I don't know of anyway to improve it.
There is Camera.setQuality but it is only for use with flash media center.

```
import flash.media.Camera;  
var cam = Camera.getCamera();  

var video = new Video( );  
video.attachCamera( cam );  
addChild( video );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that you can "improve" your video is by setting the smoothing property to true for the video.

```
video.smoothing = true;
```

Also remember that there are a lot of factors that can affect the quality of the video. Connection, camera quality, bandwidth, computer processor and more.

I hope the smoothing property can help you some.

Comment: That does improve the quality. The setmode() method does the trick.